# Using multiple file descriptors with epoll

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor, epoll

Hello I am trying to use epoll in a raw ethernet server/client application

I need to monitor at least two file descriptors 
one for the connection (Raw Socket)
another for the standard input since I have to get some data from the keyboard (fileno(stdin))

I have read online that a for loop have to be created in order to add the file descriptors to the epoll instance but I can get it to work can someone help me with an example of how to implement this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I already figure it out It was not working for me because I had a typo and by the way you dont need a for loop to add the file descriptors just add one after the other. At least it work for me that I dont need to monitor that many file descriptors